# Mapping Datetime raises KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm kind of new to Python and Datascience.

I have a `DataFrame` with a timestamp column :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2019-10-22T15:13:36.000Z', '2019-07-16T02:13:36.000Z']})
                  timestamp
0  2019-10-22T15:13:36.000Z
1  2019-07-16T02:13:36.000Z
```

And a second `DataFrame` with a `Start` and `Stop` timestamp and another datetimecolumn:

```
    L=[['2019-07-16T12:25:07.000Z', '2019-07-16T00:25:07.000000Z', '2019-07-16T13:25:07.000000Z'], ['2019-03-20T09:56:29.000Z','2019-03-19T21:56:29.000000Z','2019-03-20T10:56:29.000000Z'],['2019-08-28T08:26:03.000Z', '2019-08-27T20:26:03.000000Z','2019-08-28T09:26:03.000000Z']]
    cinfo = pd.DataFrame(data=L, columns=['c_time', 'start', 'stop'])
                     c_time                        start  \
0  2019-07-16T12:25:07.000Z  2019-07-16T00:25:07.000000Z   
1  2019-03-20T09:56:29.000Z  2019-03-19T21:56:29.000000Z   
2  2019-08-28T08:26:03.000Z  2019-08-27T20:26:03.000000Z   

                          stop  
0  2019-07-16T13:25:07.000000Z  
1  2019-03-20T10:56:29.000000Z  
2  2019-08-28T09:26:03.000000Z
```

Now what I want to do is:

For each row in the `firstdataset`, I want to check the timestamp and if its between `Start` and `Stop` of the second dataset, I want to give the `c_time` value given in the second dataset. I also want it to set `c_time` to `NaN` if it is not between any `Start` and `Stop`.

So for my example, I'd have

```
                  timestamp  c_time
0  2019-10-22T15:13:36.000Z  NaN
1  2019-07-16T02:13:36.000Z  2019-07-16T12:25:07.000Z
```

I tried to do this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2019-10-22T15:13:36.000Z']})
L=[['2019-07-16T12:25:07.000Z', '2019-07-16T00:25:07.000000Z', '2019-07-16T13:25:07.000000Z'], ['2019-03-20T09:56:29.000Z','2019-03-19T21:56:29.000000Z','2019-03-20T10:56:29.000000Z'],['2019-08-28T08:26:03.000Z', '2019-08-27T20:26:03.000000Z','2019-08-28T09:26:03.000000Z']]

cinfo = pd.DataFrame(data=L, columns=['c_time', 'start', 'stop'])
cinfo.start=pd.to_datetime(cinfo.start)
cinfo.stop=pd.to_datetime(cinfo.stop)

cinterval = cinfo.set_index(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(cinfo.start, cinfo.stop, closed='both'))['c_time']

df['c_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).map(cinterval)
```

But I am getting a KeyError `KeyError: 1571757216000000000`

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Python version you are working on ?

Comment: @KhileshChauhan Python 3.7.3

Comment: Its working in python 3.8. Code and snippet in answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: working code snapshot]

Code to try :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2019-10-22T15:13:36.000Z']})
L=[['2019-07-16T12:25:07.000Z', '2019-07-16T00:25:07.000000Z', '2019-07-16T13:25:07.000000Z'], ['2019-03-20T09:56:29.000Z','2019-03-19T21:56:29.000000Z','2019-03-20T10:56:29.000000Z'],['2019-08-28T08:26:03.000Z', '2019-08-27T20:26:03.000000Z','2019-08-28T09:26:03.000000Z']]

cinfo = pd.DataFrame(data=L, columns=['c_time', 'start', 'stop'])
cinfo.start=pd.to_datetime(cinfo.start)
cinfo.stop=pd.to_datetime(cinfo.stop)

cinterval = cinfo.set_index(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(cinfo.start, cinfo.stop, closed='both'))['c_time']

df['c_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).map(cinterval)
print(df)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve this using Python 3.7 or 3.6?